# I'm having trouble displaying my results in different rows using SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to display 2 rows of 5 but i can't seem to think of the logic behind. Help is appreciated.

```
$sql = " SELECT  KEYWORD, COUNT(*) Count_Duplicate
FROM {$_POST['btn']}
GROUP BY KEYWORD
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10";
```

This is my SQL query part and i echo it like this,

```
echo   $row['KEYWORD'] .", " ."  "  ;
```

Comment: what do you mean display 2 rows of 5 ? you only have 5 rows in the db? change LIMIT 10 to LIMIT 5 ??

Comment: The results now show 10 words because i limit it to 10. I want to break the 10 words into 2 rows of 5.

Comment: do you want them to be displayed In a table?

Comment: Yes please, a table would be more neat

Answer (score 1):

You can use limit with offset value it will help you for lazy-loading also.
Limit can be change in this way.

```
$sql = " SELECT  KEYWORD, COUNT(*) Count_Duplicate 
          FROM {$_POST['btn']} GROUP BY KEYWORD HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 2,OFFSET 10";
```

Offset shows the index upto which the rows will be select, and you can ignore OFFSET use limit as LIMIT 2, 10; only.

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
$sql = " SELECT  KEYWORD, COUNT(*) as Count_Duplicate FROM {$_POST['btn']} GROUP BY KEYWORD
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 2";
```

use loop for display results